# Jest duplicate manual mock warning within Nx workspace

Tags: axios, jestjs, ts-jest, nrwl-nx, jest-mock-axios

I am facing an issue with Jest in my Nx workspace where I have a React app, several libraries, and a buildable library. Each library and the React app has its own Jest configuration, and I have a base Jest configuration that is extended within the libraries. Additionally, I have a `__mocks__` folder in each library and the root of the repository to make axios work as expected.

However, when running tests for the React app, I encounter the following warning:

```
jest-haste-map: duplicate manual mock found: axios
  The following files share their name; please delete one of them:
    * <rootDir>/__mocks__/axios.js
    * <rootDir>/libs/redux/__mocks__/axios.js
    * <rootDir>/libs/my-custom-lib/__mocks__/axios.js
    * <rootDir>/libs/services/__mocks__/axios.js
```

This warning is due to the existence of the `__mocks__` folder multiple times, including in the root of the repository for the main app to function properly.

I have tried creating a central `__mocks__` folder, using moduleDirectories within my Jest configuration, renamed the `axios.js` files based on the library names and tried some apporaches within the `jest.setup.ts` file. None of them seem to resolve the issue.

Is there a recommended way to structure Jest configurations and `__mocks__` folders in an Nx standalone repository with a React app and Nx libraries to avoid these warnings? My goal is to have only ony `__mocks__` folder in the root of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem, here is the solution that worked for me.

Place the `__mocks__` directory at the root (same level as your `node_modules`) of your Nx workspace (works for standalone repositories as well as mono repositories): `myWorkspace/__mocks__`.

In your `jest.preset.js/ts` file (at the root level as well) do the following:

```
const nxPreset = require('@nx/jest/preset').default;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset,
  roots: ["<rootDir>", path.resolve(__dirname, "./__mocks__")]
 };
```

This way you only need one single `__mocks__` folder that is also recognized by the Nx libraries inside the same repository.

Works with the latest Nx version (17.2.8) as well.